# Can android VideoView seekTo a previous frame (backwards) consistently and accurately?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Can android `VideoView` seekTo a previous frame (backward) consistently and accurately? The goal is to allow the user to rewind either 1 frame, 33ms, or approximately 1000ms when paused. I can get the `VideoView` to seek backward, but not consistently or accurately.

Comment: It'll seek to the nearest sync frame. How often those occur depends on the way the video was generated. VideoView is just SurfaceView + MediaPlayer, so look at the MediaPlayer documentation.